# Why do I have an 'int' object is not iterable error?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm practicing my coding skills and trying to solve [Path with Maximum Gold problem from LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/path-with-maximum-gold/). My current code is below

```
from typing import List

class Solution:
     def getMaximumGold(self, grid: List[List[int]]) -> int:
          total_gold = 0
          m = len(grid)
          n = len(grid[0])
          for i in range(m):
               for j in range(n):
                    if grid[i][j] != 0:
                         visited = []
                         path_from_cell = self.searchForPath(m, n, i, j, grid, visited)
                         total_gold = max(total_gold, path_from_cell)
          return total_gold

     def searchForPath(self, m, n, i, j: int, grid: List[List[int]], visited) -> int:
          if grid[i][j] == 0 or [i,j] in visited or i<0 or j<0 or i>=m or j>=n:
               return 0
          else:
               visited.append([i,j])
               left = self.searchForPath(m, n, i, j-1, grid, visited)
               right = self.searchForPath(m, n, i, j+1, grid, visited)
               up = self.searchForPath(m, n, i-1, j, grid, visited)
               down = self.searchForPath(m, n, i+1, j, grid, visited)
               visited.remove([i,j])
               return max(left,max(right,max(up,max(down)))) + grid[i][j]

print(Solution().getMaximumGold(grid = [[0,6,0],[5,8,7],[0,9,0]]))
```

It throws the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hasek/Documents/Programming/leetcode.py", line 28, in <module>
    print(Solution().getMaximumGold(grid = [[0,6,0],[5,8,7],[0,9,0]]))
  File "/home/hasek/Documents/Programming/leetcode.py", line 12, in getMaximumGold
    path_from_cell = self.searchForPath(m, n, i, j, grid, visited)
  File "/home/hasek/Documents/Programming/leetcode.py", line 24, in searchForPath
    down = self.searchForPath(m, n, i+1, j, grid, visited)
  File "/home/hasek/Documents/Programming/leetcode.py", line 21, in searchForPath
    left = self.searchForPath(m, n, i, j-1, grid, visited)
  File "/home/hasek/Documents/Programming/leetcode.py", line 26, in searchForPath
    return max(left,max(right,max(up,max(down)))) + grid[i][j]
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

I can't see what's wrong. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you mean: max( (left,right,up,down) )  ?

Comment: What did you think `max(down)` means?

Comment: @quamrana, this was helpful, thank you. I also corrected other errors that were in my code afterwards.

Comment: Excellent. Also that is the nature of errors. They often hide other errors. Its better to write code in tiny little chunks so that there is very little space for an error to hide in.